Jetson TX2 is unreachable over ethernet
I’ve managed to connect my TX2 Developer Kit ( Ubuntu 18.04 installed with JetPack 4.6.5 ) to my laptop ( Ubuntu 20.04 ) with ethernet cable but neither I can ping or connect via SSH. These are the steps I’ve done so far:
1- Add static IP to my laptop → 192.168.0.16/24
2- Add static IP to my TX2 → 192.168.0.10/24
3- Connect with ethernet cable
4- Confirm the IP’s has come on both devices
5- Send ping from both devices but couldn’t send
6- Try to connect with ssh but could’t do it either
Later, I connected both devices on the same Wifi and tried to connect with SSH and succeed.
My question is how to connect SSH with Ethernet cable?
ifconfig on both devices:
TX2:
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 192.168.0.10 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.0.255
inet6 fe80::837:e1d1:b58a:ee04 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20
ether X:X:X:X:X:X txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 20 bytes 3153 (3.1 KB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 49 bytes 5328 (5.3 KB)
TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
device interrupt 41

Laptop:
enp2s0f1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
inet 192.168.0.16 netmask 255.255.255.0 broadcast 192.168.0.255
inet6 fe80::9e41:5f43:830f:6fb1 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20
ether Y:Y:Y:Y:Y:Y txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet)
RX packets 109 bytes 19014 (19.0 KB)
RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
TX packets 475 bytes 73599 (73.5 KB)
TX errors 5 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0

.............................
EDIT
.............................
tcdump command output's has added...
Note: I've hidden the mac address (X:X:X:X:X:X)
Laptop:
listening on enp2s0f1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
23:44:36.435550 IP zeobora-Nitro-AN515-42.48772 > 192.168.0.10.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1127544129, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3830305913 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:44:37.456088 IP zeobora-Nitro-AN515-42.48772 > 192.168.0.10.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1127544129, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3830306934 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:44:39.472016 IP zeobora-Nitro-AN515-42.48772 > 192.168.0.10.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1127544129, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3830308950 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:44:41.488014 ARP, Request who-has 192.168.0.10 tell zeobora-Nitro-AN515-42, length 28
23:44:41.488669 ARP, Reply 192.168.0.10 is-at X:X:X:X:X:X (oui Unknown), length 46
23:44:43.536448 IP zeobora-Nitro-AN515-42.48772 > 192.168.0.10.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1127544129, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3830313014 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:44:51.728448 IP zeobora-Nitro-AN515-42.48772 > 192.168.0.10.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1127544129, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3830321206 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:44:52.076570 IP zeobora-Nitro-AN515-42.39242 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 173
23:44:53.080123 IP zeobora-Nitro-AN515-42.39242 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 173
23:44:54.080491 IP zeobora-Nitro-AN515-42.39242 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 173
23:44:55.081248 IP zeobora-Nitro-AN515-42.39242 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 173
23:45:06.788448 IP zeobora-Nitro-AN515-42.mdns > mdns.mcast.net.mdns: 0 [9q] PTR (QM)? _nfs._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipp._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipps._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ftp._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _webdav._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _webdavs._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _sftp-ssh._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _smb._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _afpovertcp._tcp.local. (141)
23:45:07.856020 IP zeobora-Nitro-AN515-42.48772 > 192.168.0.10.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1127544129, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3830337334 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0

TX2:
listening on eth0, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
23:44:37.785101 IP 192.168.0.16.48772 > ubuntu.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1127544129, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3830305913 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:44:38.805644 IP 192.168.0.16.48772 > ubuntu.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1127544129, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3830306934 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:44:40.821750 IP 192.168.0.16.48772 > ubuntu.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1127544129, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3830308950 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:44:42.837617 ARP, Request who-has ubuntu tell 192.168.0.16, length 46
23:44:42.837816 ARP, Reply ubuntu is-at X:X:X:X:X:X (oui Unknown), length 28
23:44:44.886177 IP 192.168.0.16.48772 > ubuntu.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1127544129, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3830313014 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:44:53.078190 IP 192.168.0.16.48772 > ubuntu.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1127544129, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3830321206 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0
23:44:53.426255 IP 192.168.0.16.39242 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 173
23:44:54.429881 IP 192.168.0.16.39242 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 173
23:44:55.430212 IP 192.168.0.16.39242 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 173
23:44:56.430932 IP 192.168.0.16.39242 > 239.255.255.250.1900: UDP, length 173
23:45:08.138227 IP 192.168.0.16.mdns > mdns.mcast.net.mdns: 0 [9q] PTR (QM)? _nfs._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipp._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ipps._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _ftp._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _webdav._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _webdavs._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _sftp-ssh._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _smb._tcp.local. PTR (QM)? _afpovertcp._tcp.local. (141)
23:45:09.205729 IP 192.168.0.16.48772 > ubuntu.ssh: Flags [S], seq 1127544129, win 64240, options [mss 1460,sackOK,TS val 3830337334 ecr 0,nop,wscale 7], length 0


Can you show the information from ip link and maybe also from bridge link? Can you also run e.g. tcpdump -e -n -i eth0 on one system and check if it receives any packets while trying to connect from the other system?

Both the TX2's eth0 and Laptop's enp2s0f1 listings show nonzero values for RX and TX packets & byte counts. So something is being transferred on the link. Does each kernel log have a Link is up message? Do the RJ-45 port activity LEDs indicate activity?

@grawity_u1686 I edited my post .

@sawdust yes TX2's RJ-45 port's LED is turning yellow.

TX2 isn't with me right now, I'll try to add the rest of the what you ask as soon as possible.

That tcpdump output shows that TCP packets do arrive (adding the -n option would've made it easier to compare the two outputs, but it's good enough either way), so the next thing to check would be the firewall... though, it might be useful to do the same tcpdump check while trying to connect in the opposite direction, but I'm suspecting the firewall.

ufw is disabled on both devices
sudo ufw status
Status: inactive

What's the IP range in your main network?

Changing the static IP's (both Jetson TX2's and my laptop's) to 10.0.0.X/8 (10.0.0.10/8 and 10.0.0.16/8) from 192.168.0.X/24 (192.168.0.10/24 and 192.168.0.16/24) has solved my problem. Do you have any idea why?
Note: I was also asked this question in Nvidia Forum and they solved it by this suggestion but I couldn't find why.
